# how to pass data in body of API request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to update some info in my database using `PUT` request and Django rest framework

I need to update `max_date` parameter by passing the value in the body of the query (pass True or False)
but i have 0 ideas how to do it

i only know how to update something by passing a variable in the url, like `api/config/max_date/<int:boolean_by_number>`

my URLs:

```py
urlpatterns_config = [
    path('all/', api_config.APIListConfig.as_view(), name='api info config'),
    path('forever/', api_config.APIForever.as_view(), name='put or get forever config'),
    path('max_date/', api_config.APIMaxDate.as_view(), name='put or get max_date config')
]
```

my API file:

```py
class APIMaxDate(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> JsonResponse:

        config = Configuration.objects.get(name='max_date')

        data = {
            f"{config.name}": config.value
        }
    
        return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> JsonResponse:

        return JsonResponse({}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Please use the code fields to post code, rather than via images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If values are passed via PUT, you can access them in django like so:

```py
max_date = request.PUT.get('max_date', False)
if max_date:
    # continue to use max_date to update your db instance
```

Comment: the problem is there is no such method `PUT` in request

Comment: oh, thanks man, you gave me direction on where to think and i solved it
so this what helped me:

```python
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> JsonResponse:

        if request.method == 'PUT':
            print(request.data)

        return JsonResponse({}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

by doing this i can access the data i send